# Drawing out of a bin without replacement

Tags: probability-theory, binomial-coefficients, balls-in-bins

So we play a lottery with the numbers from 1 to 60, and we draw 5 of these numbers. Can someone please explain why the probability that a certain number x appears in this lottery is

$$PR[x appears] = \frac {\binom {59}{4}}{\binom {60}{5}} = \frac {5}{60} $$

Because this doesn't feel natural or logic to me. I know that the denominator stands for all possible permutations of 5 numbers drawn out of this 60. But why is the numerator that $\binom {59}{4} $ ? Are these all possible permutations were we have already drawn the 5?

Comment: Yes, if we fix a number, we have $4$ out of $59$. And the probability is what we would intuitively expect : we have a chance of $\frac{1}{60}$ and $5$ chances to draw a given number.

Comment: The probability can be easily found without the formula as follows : Imagine, we draw all the $60$ numbers and only consider the first five draws. The given number is at any given position with probability $\frac{1}{60}$. It appears, if the position is smaller than $6$, so we get that the probability that the number occurs is $5\cdot \frac{1}{60}$

Comment: Ok cool. Yeah that's a good way of thinking of it. It just doesn't seem natural to get this probability, since we draw without replacement. But I guess it makes sence now to me which is good

Comment: Another approach is to use the converse probability. 1 minus the probability that a certain number does not appear: $1-\frac{59}{60}\cdot \frac{58}{59}\cdot\frac{57}{58}\cdot\frac{56}{57}\cdot\frac{55}{56}=1-\frac{55}{60}=\frac{5}{60}=\frac1{12}$